# scrolll in div pushing bottom or left

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am doing an MVC 5, bootstrap Application.

I have a page with HTML tags. I know that in order to move up or down a page content it is necessary to embed inside a div with fixed width and height, so you have to scroll on both directions to reach all contents.

What I try to do, is to simulate phones scrolling, i mean, "push" (one touch) bottom or left in order to automatically scroll bottom or left inside the div.

```html
 <div id="Div1" class="MenuUserPpal">
                <div class="dvParPal" 
                    <img id="imgConf2" class="dvPPalImg" src="~/Content/Images/Iconos/Photos.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="dvParPal">
                    <img id="img22" class="dvPPalImg" src="~/Content/Images/Iconos/Activities.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="dvParPal" title="Mis Foro" >
                    <img id="img42" class="dvPPalImg" src="~/Content/Images/Iconos/Foro.png" />
                </div>
               
                    <div class="dvParPal"  >
                        <img id="img52" class="dvPPalImg" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture)" />
                    </div>
               
                <div class="dvParPal" >
                    <img id="img12" class="dvPPalImg" src="~/Content/Images/Iconos/groups.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="dvParPal"  >
                    <div class="dvParPalImg" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dvParPal">
                    <img id="img8" class="dvPPalImg" src="~/Content/Images/Iconos/alerts.png" />
                </div>
            
                    <div id="dvMantenimiento" class="dvParPal"  >
                        <img id="img7" class="dvPPalImg" src="~/Content/Images/Iconos/man.png" />
                    </div>
            </div>
```

It is a way to do it? with Jquery o bootstrap or HTML?

Thanks

Comment: You can use either javascript or Jquery.. If you post a fiddle of your code, we can get a solution...

Comment: Add code so we can help you out!

Comment: Add code I need to scroll. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
```

with jQuery to scroll to bottom or left.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scroll bars to always be there.

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:scroll;">
```

If you want the scroll bars to only show up when content is greater than the div.

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:auto;">
```

Comment: I want to scroll using "swipe" not scrolling with the mouse.